# Rabbit listener method is not getting invoked with the incoming message

Tags: java, rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp, spring-rabbit

I have a method to consume messages in similar line as shown below:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "${com.rabbimq.myQueue}")
public void receive(String msg, Channel channel, @Header(AmqpHeaders.DELIVERY_TAG) long tag)
        throws IOException {
    log.info("Received msg: {}",msg);
    channel.basicAck(tag, false);   
}
```

This works fine when I execute it as a SpringBoot project. But when I build this project and put it as a dependency in my other project, it no longer consumes the message. I want this to be a generic project which can be leveraged by my other projects. I have put some loggers in this "message consumption" project and I can see that all the beans are getting created. But it's not invoking this particular method. Any pointers here is really appreciated.

Comment: The class that this method is in must be declared as a `@Bean` or, if it is a `@Component`, it must be in a package that is scanned for component scanning. If neither of those are a problem, please provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: Thank you Gary for your comments. Yes, you are right. It was a silly mistake. I missed declaring the class as a @Bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class that this method is in must be declared as a @Bean or, if it is a @Component, it must be in a package that is scanned for component scanning.